# Combine CSV files into XLS or XLSX on AWS S3

Tags: python, excel, amazon-s3, xlsxwriter

I have code running as AWS Lambda that queries internal database and generates files in different formats. The files are generated in parts and uploaded to S3 using multi-part upload:

```
self.mpu = self.s3_client.create_multipart_upload(
        Bucket=self.bucket_name,
        ContentType=self.get_content_type(),
        Expires=self.expire_daytime,
        Key=self.filename,
    )
```

and

```
response = self.s3_client.upload_part(
        Bucket=self.bucket_name,
        Key=self.filename,
        PartNumber=self.part_number,
        UploadId=self.upload_id,
        Body=data
    )
self.current_part_info.update({
        'PartNumber': self.part_number,
        'ETag': response['ETag']
    })
```

One of the formats I need to support is XLS or XLSX. It's fairly easy to create multiple CSV files on S3. But is it possible to combine them directly on S3 into XLS/XLSX without downloading them?

My current code generates an XLSX file in memory, creates a local file, and then uploads it to S3:

```py
import xlsxwriter

self.workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(self.filename)
# download CSV files...
for sheet_name, sheet_info in sheets.items():
    sheet = self.workbook.add_worksheet(name=sheet_name)
    # code that does formatting
    for...     # loop through rows
        for... # loop thru columns
            sheet.write(row, col, col_str)

self.workbook.close()
```

This works fine for small queries, but the users will want to use it for a large amount of data.

When I run it with large queries, it runs out of memory. AWS Lambda has limited memory and limited disk space, and I'm hitting those limits.

Is it possible to combine CSV files into XLS or XLSX somehow without holding the entire file in local space (both memory and disk space are a problem)?

Comment: can you please try using xlsxwriter in Constant Memory mode? https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_memory.html
if not then you have to create chunks of files.

Comment: @SebinSunny local disk space is also a problem